# Can't find defaultResourceProxyImpl class in osmdroid 6.0.1

Tags: android, openstreetmap

I want to use OpenStreetMap. I can show map and I can use zoom, but I can't use Marker system 'cause not found defaultResourceProxyImpl class. I 'm trying [this example](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/How-to-use-the-osmdroid-library)

My manifest file like this:

```
dependencies {
...
implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:6.0.1'
implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-wms:6.0.1'
implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-mapsforge:6.0.1'
implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-geopackage:6.0.1'
implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-third-party:6.0.1'
}
```

Comment: According to https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/issues/1238 "It was removed a few years ago". Unfortunately you didn't show us your code so we can't really help you.

Comment: So how can I use markers, do u know that?

Comment: https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/How-to-use-the-osmdroid-library#how-do-i-place-icons-on-the-map-with-a-click-listener has an example for adding icons to the map.

Comment: I looked that, if I will use this example, I will need same class. There is: https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/How-to-use-the-osmdroid-library#create-a-custom-resource-proxy

Comment: I was referring to the example creating `ItemizedOverlayWithFocus` and adding `OverlayItem`s, see my link again.